# Content-Length is being stripped

Tags: python, web-services, web.py

I'm using webpy 0.34, python 2.6.6. I'm also using mimerender. I am trying to include the content-length in my http response, but for some reason the header is being removed. I say removed because I can create custom headers just fine, and I can see those headers on the client. But when I try to set content-length, the header never makes it to the client. I've tried including the header in the web.created object (as shown) and I've also tried using

```
web.header('Content-Length', len(data))
```

What am I doing wrong and/or not understanding about how this code works?

```
render_json = lambda **args: json.JSONEncoder().encode(args)

class MyHandler:
    @mimerender(
            default = 'json',
            json = render_json,
            )
    def POST(self):
        data = "abcd"
        raise web.created(data, headers={'Content-Length': len(data)})
```

Comment: Note, you've got the wrong tag -- you're using web.py, but you have added the web2py tag (they are not the same framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is sent as chunked (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`), then the `Content-Length` header must be omitted, [as per RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4):

> 1. [snip]

> 2. If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and
>    has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
>    defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6),
>    unless the message is terminated by closing the connection.

> 3. If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its
>    decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
>    transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent
>    if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
>    header field is present). If a message is received with both a
>    Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
>    the latter MUST be ignored.

Comment: Thats exactly what is happening. Thanks!