# Content-Length-Header not set in Jersey Client request

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey Client to access a webservice, like this: 
`response = 
r.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).header("content-length", 0).post(String.class);`
where r is a WebResource

However, the Webservice returns 411 - Content-Length is missing.

using tcpdump, i found out that i am able to specify custom headers, i.e. `.header("myheader", 0)` works fine.

So it seems that jersey is deleting the content-length header for some reasons.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5553151/139010) answer it?

Comment: wow. going to try that out. sorry, actually, i did search, but was focused on java and jersey.

Comment: no, this does not solve my problem. the transfer-encoding header is not set in the outgoing packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content length of a call is computed by Jersey Client, it cannot be set.
Paul Sandoz — a well known commiter on the project — have answered [a similar question](http://markmail.org/message/krebqm6txxmhyame#query:jersey%20http%20content-length+page:1+mid:2u72tcbmyhipsmvs+state:results):

> **Q:** I think that "Content-Length"
> header is not being set automatically.
>
> **A:** The Jersey runtime [...]
> determine the length of content.

If you need further informations, please explain what result did you expect from POSTing a String to a Resource with an empty size.

Answer (score 8):

I actually had a requirement to use an empty POST request for a Restful webservice.

If you specify an empty string as the second parameter of post method, Jersey will create the Content-Length header with the value of 0.

e.g.
`response = r.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).post(String.class, "");`