# Jersey 1x does not send Content-Length header in request

Tags: java, jersey-client

I'd like to send a Content-Length header in an HTTP request using Jersey client 1.18 over Dropwizard.

LoggingFilter shows that the request does not contain Content-Length and the OP says it doesn't receive it.

However, when I try to add it manually, I get an `org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present` error.
Here's my code:

```
byte[] entity = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(msg);
response = client.resource(uri)
                 .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .header(TransactionIdUtils.TRANSACTION_ID_HEADER, transactionId)
                 .header(CREDENTIALS_HEADER, this.credentials)                    
                 .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, entity.length)
                 .post(ClientResponse.class, entity);
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Edit: Here's my `LoggingFilter` code:

```
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(new JulFacade()));

//a class for redirecting Jersey logging to sl4j
    private static class JulFacade extends java.util.logging.Logger {
        JulFacade() {
            super("Jersey", null);
        }

        @Override
        public void info(String msg) {
            LOGGER.info(msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue when you send it without setting the content-length?
Your current error might be related to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639889/content-length-header-not-set-in-jersey-client-request)